# how to use pyinstaller for intel mac on m1 mac

Tags: pyinstaller

I want to use pyinstaller for intel mac or universal2 on m1 mac.

i try to use it using "--target-arch universal2" or "--target-arch x86_64" according to pyinstaller manual. but it can't

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in 
sys.exit(_console_script_run())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/**main**.py", line 214, in _console_script_run
run()
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/**main**.py", line 198, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/**main**.py", line 69, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1069, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1009, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/inewtern1.spec", line 18, in 
exe = EXE(
^^^^
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 609, in **init**
self.pkg = PKG(
^^^^
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 238, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 289, in assemble
src_name = process_collected_binary(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 272, in process_collected_binary
osxutils.binary_to_target_arch(cached_name, target_arch, display_name=src_name)
File "/Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 339, in binary_to_target_arch
raise IncompatibleBinaryArchError(f"{display_name} is not a fat binary!")
PyInstaller.utils.osx.IncompatibleBinaryArchError: /Users/gwonhyeonjun/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-311-darwin.so is not a fat binary!

There showing this error.

what should i do?

i use anaconda.

i think python is for m1 mac.
SO i have to change it for univalsal2
but i don't know how to do it at anaconda